# angular nested ng-repeat not working on third level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using the following nested `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="programme in programmes">
 <h4>{{programme.title}}</h4>
  <div ng-repeat="exercise in programme.exercises">
    {{exercise.exerciseName}}
      <ul ng-repeat"image in exercise.images">
        <li>{{image}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following number of objects (the below represents one `programme`)

```
[
{
    "exerciseDescription": "Kneeling on the gym ball. ",
    "exerciseID": 92,
    "exerciseName": "4 pt Kneeling on Gym Ball - Arm and Leg Lift  ",
    "images": [
        345,
        346,
        347
    ]
},
{
    "exerciseDescription": "Laying on the gym ball with the ball/ weight directly above your head. ",
    "exerciseID": 32,
    "exerciseName": "Gym Ball Bridge - Double arm Med ball  ",
    "images": [
        110,
        111,
        112
    ]
},
{
    "exerciseDescription": "Sit on a gym ball with the bony points at the bottom of your bum very top of the leg in contact with the ball.",
    "exerciseID": 1,
    "exerciseName": "Neutral Spine on Gym Ball ",
    "images": [
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
    ]
}
]
```

This works perfectly for all others apart from the third level `image in exercise.image`

Comment: Where is third level image? Elaborate your problem, as of now is its very unclear

Comment: The data I have shown represents ONE programme therefore the images are the third level in my application however not in this example... I cannot get the whole example's data as its a class in parse.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the `ng-repeat`, you're missing the `=`:

```
      <ul ng-repeat="image in exercise.images">
        <li>{{image}}</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Oh my word! Stupid me! Should I leave the question on here or delete my stupidity?

Comment: @Taylorsuk lol, it happens mate, no worries :-) I've got some lying around here too, I'm sure...